# verifying properties of a certain relation

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**Problem**:Let M be a set of 2 elements or more. Let $P(M)$ be the set of all possible subsets of $M$. We define the relation $R$ on $P(M)$ by saying $(U,V) \in R$ if and only if $U\cap V \neq \oslash$ Which of the following qualities does the relation have: transitive, reflexive, symmetrical.

**What I don't understand:**
does $(U,V)\in{R} $ is some notation for $(U,V)$ verifying $R$ ? if so what convention of notation is this?

**My answer**

It's reflexive since $U \cap U = \emptyset \implies U= \emptyset $ and it should be in M since it's the set of all subsets, reciprocally $U = \emptyset \in M \implies U \cap U = \emptyset$ so $U \cap U = \emptyset  \implies (U,U) \in M$

for symmetry it's verified since $U \cap V= \emptyset \iff V \cap U = \emptyset \iff (U,V) \in M $

It's also not necessarily (not sure)transitive since

$U \cap X= \emptyset $and $X\cap V = \emptyset$
is not  equivalent to $V \cap U = \emptyset$ (but I think we should find a counter example here)

Is how I am thinking about the problem correct? Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: $R$ is reflexive if $(U,U)\in R$ for **all** $U$, but you showed $(U,U)\in R\implies U=\emptyset$! -- Also, check again: Apparently $R$ is defined as $(U,V)\in R\iff U\cap V\color{red}\ne \emptyset$

Comment: Just exhibit a single element $U$ of $P(M)$ for which you can show that $U\cap U\ne \emptyset $ is false. -- Likewise, you can show that $R$ is *definitely* not transitive if you use the given fact that $M$ has at least two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a relation on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$, so its elements are ordered pairs of elements of $A$. By analogy with such familiar usages as $x\le y$ and $U\subseteq V$ we often write $U\mathrel{R}V$ instead of $\langle U,V\rangle\in R$, but writing $\langle U,V\rangle\in R$ is not a convention: it’s based on the actual definition of a relation.

$R$ is almost but not quite reflexive: for $A\in P(M)$ we have $\langle A,A\rangle\in R$ iff $A\cap A\ne\varnothing$ iff $A\ne\varnothing$. If we restricted $R$ to the **non-empty** subsets of $M$, it would be reflexive, but on $P(M)$ it is not reflexive.

It is symmetric, since intersection is a commutative operation.

It is not transitive, and you do indeed need a counterexample to demonstrate this. You’ll need to use the fact that $|M|\ge 2$. Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct elements of $M$. Then $\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\in P(M)$, $\{a\}\cap\{a,b\}\ne\varnothing\ne\{a,b\}\cap\{b\}$, and $\{a\}\cap\{b\}=\varnothing$, so $\left\langle\{a\},\{a,b\}\right\rangle\in R$ and $\left\langle\{a,b\},\{b\}\right\rangle\in R$, but $\left\langle\{a\},\{b\}\right\rangle\notin R$.